# Searches with "is:question" and an unquoted string don't return results

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

If I search for a string, and constrain it to questions only, I get no results. For example, searching for [`[sql-server] is:question nolock`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D%20is%3Aquestion%20nolock) gives no results.

However, if I put quotes around the string ([`[sql-server] is:question "nolock"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+is%3Aquestion+%22nolock%22)) it works as expected.

If I search for answers ([`[sql-server] is:answer nolock`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D%20is%3Aanswer%20nolock)) it also works as expected.

Comment: Was just today doing this exact type of search and got jack squat. Thought there were just no results. Damnit. (runs off and tries it) sommbitch muh results!

Comment: Same here. I run a series of manual, bookmarked searches to find edit-worthy questions, and today a good number of them have been unavailable (0 results on searches that I expect to return thousands of posts). I've spotted this previously, but this unexpected behaviour has not lasted this long before.

Comment: They were [doing some work earlier today that might be impacting it](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/910495256357081088), I've poked the devs.

Comment: I also just noticed this and it actually turns out that the search currently can't find any questions whatsoever, it only searches through answers (regardless of search query).

Comment: @bluefeet thanks, though I noticed this happening yesterday as well

Comment: @halfer I'm curious what those searches are. How do they determine if they are edit-worthy?

Comment: @NH., well, they still require human judgement. For example, [consider this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=plz%20help%20is%3aquestion%20closed%3ano) - it helps indicate that the OP saw fit to use txtspk, and to add please-help fluff. I'll periodically make that search, and explore some of the questions within at random. Where there is more than a couple of things to edit, based on removing fluff and improving readability, I will edit and try to fix all of them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A fix for this is rolling out now. A bug slipped in our version 2 code where Elastic changes behavior and testing missed it. We'll add some bits to our test plan for the Elastic v5 upgrade we hope to do next week...the way queries change is a bit brutal from v1 to v2 to v5, as we get on latest we're trying our best not to introduce regressions but we missed one here.

Sorry for creating trouble, we really are trying to improve all of the backend so we can finally give search some proper love for users.

Comment: Great, looking forward to improved search in the future. (Especially for dupes!)

Comment: Nick, [is this problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357002/472495) related?