# Search with is:closed and high page numbers are unexpectedly empty

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I think I have found another search bug, so this may be related [to this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356834).

Consider a search with a `closed:yes` filter, like so. This produces the first page of ~644,016 results:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=tab=votes&q=closed%3ayes

The pagination device indicates there are [42935 pages of results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=42935&tab=Relevance&q=closed%3ayes) to peruse. However, this search is empty. It looks like the search is no longer populated from around page 670.

Comment: There are really 42935 pages of results, but only the first 666 pages with a pagesize of 15 can be accessed. That's actually the 10,000 first results.

Comment: @Cœur: I'm making a large pentagram out of salt on my lounge floor, just in case!

Comment: :( breaking change in Elastic 2.x that we're investigating a solution to. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: @halfer Rest easy... it's really [the number 616](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/616_(number)) you need to worry about!

Comment: @DeanWard: this looks like it is resolved now. Can the question be marked as such?

Comment: @DeanWard [Broken again now?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?page=201&tab=Newest&q=%22Try%20it%20online!%22) ([page 200 works fine and show 676 pages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?page=200&tab=Newest&q=%22Try%20it%20online!%22))

Comment: @DeanWard It seems to have broken again.

Comment: I've been getting this too @gparyani - results that definitely ought to bring back something sporadically come back with zero results.

Answer (score 11):

The count is correct, but search results for any query are limited to 10,000 (or 9,999?) results being displayed.

That's:

- 666 pages with pagesize=15
- 333 pages with pagesize=30
- 200 pages with pagesize=50

Comment: Ah, this is not a bug? This must have changed at some point, since it used to work.

Comment: For example, I used to run the search in the question with very high page numbers, to see if some questions could do with a delete vote. I am not sure if there is any way to sort the query (low votes first), which would be another way of solving the problem.

Comment: @halfer it may have changed yesterday, as ElasticSearch was not working for an hour: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301257/are-there-elastic-search-indexing-issues-currently

Comment: Ah, thanks. Yes, the other post I linked to in my question was about an Elasticsearch bug too.